# Finding the location of admin_ca, cluster_ca and admin_cert in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, concourse

Basically, I am trying to deploy a docker image on K8s in a concourse pipeline. I want to use this `resource` to deploy.
https://github.com/jcderr/concourse-kubernetes-resource#installing

However, I coudn't exactly figure out the values of

```
cluster_ca: _base64 encoded CA pem_
admin_key: _base64 encoded key pem_
admin_cert: _base64 encoded certificate_
```

For finding the `cluster_ca`, I tried to execute a command like the following:

```
kubectl config view --raw -o json | jq -r '.clusters[0].cluster."certificate-authority-data"' | tr -d '"' | base64 --decode
```

And for the `admin_ca`, I logged into one of the containers in the cluster and `cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`

I am not sure if these two values are correct. Also, I am not sure what `admin_key` is.

Could someone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following three commands to identify the cluster_ca, admin_cert and admin_key. Assuming you have set the current context on the kubernetes-admin

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-13]# kubectl config current-context
kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
```

Command for cluster_ca (Output will be Encoded in base64)

```
kubectl config view current-context --raw -o json | ./jq -r '.clusters[].cluster."certificate-authority-data"'
```

Command for admin_cert (Output will be Encoded in base64)

```
kubectl config view current-context --raw -o json | ./jq -r '.users[].user."client-certificate-data"'
```

Command for admin_key (Output will be Encoded in base64)

```
kubectl config view current-context --raw -o json | ./jq -r '.users[].user."client-key-data"'
```

Comment: > kubectl config current-context
mycontext

When I try to use the commands for `admin_cert` and `admin_key` I get 4 `null` values. Are there any steps to do before running these commands.

I can deploy new resources on k8s using the `kubectl` configured on my machine.

Comment: I have setup my cluster using kubeadm and those are default setting. If you want to get those data, you can also get it from config file. In my case config file is at `$HOME/.kube/config` when you open that config file, you can find all three `certificate-authority-data`, `client-certificate-data`, `client-key-data`.

Comment: When I do this `cat ~/.kube/config | grep client-certificate-data` or `cat ~/.kube/config | grep client-key-data` it does not return anything.
Looks like, these values are not present in the config.

The values for `certificate-authority-data` are present.

Comment: It's `kubectl`. More specifically I am using google cloud sdk.

Comment: This one is a bit simpler:
kubectl config view --raw -ojsonpath='{ .clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data }'